# React Dynamic Image

Tags: javascript, reactjs, image, react-hooks, frontend

I have the following issue with React.

```
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { useParams } from "react-router-dom";
import RecipeService from "./RecipeService";
import RecipeProfileImg from "./RecipeProfileImg";
import "../../Assets/css/recipePage.css";

const RecipeComp = () => {

    const {id} = useParams();

    const [data, setData] = useState({});

    /*const [data, setData] = useState({
        name: 'name1',
        type: 'tipo1',
        url: 'path1',
        ingredients: 'ingr1',
        method: 'meth1',
        preparationTime: 10,
        cookingTime: 10
    });*/

    useEffect(() => {
        RecipeService.readRecipeById(id).then((res) => {
            console.log(res.data.type);
            setData(res.data);
        });
    }, [id]);

    function splitIngredients(ingrs){
        const pieces = ingrs.split(", ");
        const listItems = [];
        for(let i = 0; i < pieces.length; i++){
            const elem = <li>{pieces[i]}</li>;
            listItems.push(elem);
        }
        return listItems;
    }

    return(
        <div>
            <h1>{data.name}</h1>
            <RecipeProfileImg imgSrc={require("../../Assets/Images/" + data.type + "/" + data.url)} />
            <p id={data.url}>{data.type}</p>
            <p id={data.type}>{data.url}</p>
            <div className="listsBox">
                <label className="listLab">Ingredienti:
                    <ul className="listx">
                        {
                            splitIngredients(data.ingredients)
                        }
                    </ul>
                </label>
                <label className="listLab">Tempi:
                    <ul className="listx">
                        <li>Tempo di Preparazione: {data.preparationTime} min</li>
                        <li>Tempo di Cottura: {data.cookingTime} min</li>
                    </ul>
                </label>
            </div>
            <h3 className="prepTitle">Preparazione</h3>
            <p className="methodPar">{data.method}</p>
            <a href={'/recipes/delete/' + id}>delete me</a>
            <br />
            <a href={'/recipes/update/' + id}>update me</a>
        </div>
    );
}

export default RecipeComp;
```

In this React Component I have this problem: the file reads correctly the data.url and data.type in 2) and 3) rows.
Why it doesn't do the in row 1)?

```
1) <RecipeProfileImg imgSrc={require("../../Assets/Images/" + data.type + "/" + data.url)} />
2)            <p id={data.url}>{data.type}</p>
3)            <p id={data.type}>{data.url}</p>
```

Thanks!

I've tried also to pass these values with backtick string, `../../Assets/Images/${data.type}/${data.url}`, but the result is the same: the data attributes are read correctly in all tags except in img tag.
The error in browser console is "Cannot find module './undefined/undefined'".
The path (../../Assets/Images/" + data.type + "/" + data.url) is correct.

Answer (score 0):

It's because the use effect mounts the state after the first render so in the first render data will be `{}` (i.e initial state).

Wrap your return statement inside a condition

```
return ({
    Object.keys(data).length>0 &&
    ....rest of your code
})
```